# Finding a matrix representation with respect to standard bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear map that is represented in the standard bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ by the matrix

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}2&5&-3\\1&-4&-7\end{bmatrix} $$

Find the matrix $[T]^\beta_\alpha \in M_{3x2}(\mathbb{R})$ for the following bases:

$\alpha = \{(1,1,1), (1,1,0), (1,0,0)\}$ and $\beta = \{(1,3), (2,5)\}$

I guess my confusion is how to take $T(\alpha_1)$ = T((1,1,1)) to anything. What does it mean for a linear map to be represented by the standard bases of $\mathbb{R^3}$? What does the matrix A have to do with this question?

Comment: I think there is a mistake somewhere. The matrix $A$ as you have written it represents a transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: It means that $T(x) = Ax$, nothing more. For example, $T(1,1,1) = (4,-10)$. Now, expand $(4,-10)$ with respect to the basis $\beta$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the matrix $A$ is representative of a map from $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ not from $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. So let's assume that we're dealing with the former.

> What does it mean for a linear map to be represented by the standard bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

As per what I first said, this should really say "standard bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$." Let's denote the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ by $\gamma_3$ and the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $\gamma_2$. The statement above means that $\displaystyle A = [T]_{\gamma_3}^{\gamma_2}$. In other words, if you multiply to $A$ a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ written with respect to the standard basis. The result will be the transformed vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, also written in the standard basis.

> How to take $T\left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right)$ to anything. [. . .] What does the matrix $A$ have to do with this question?

The matrix gives you the information you need about the transformation. We have that

$$
T\left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right) = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 & -3 \\ 1 & -4 & -7 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ -10 \end{pmatrix}
$$

This result is with respect to the standard basis, however. You need it to be with respect to the basis $\beta$. This means that you need to work out what $(4, -10)$ is using the basis $\beta$. The result is the first column of the matrix you are looking for. This process should be repeated for the other elements of the basis $\alpha$ to obtain the second and third columns.