# Matrix representation with respect to the basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $A = \left[\begin{matrix} 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 8 & 5 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$ and consider $A$ as a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$ using the standard bases. Find the matrix representation of $A$ with resepect to the basis $\left\{\space\left[\begin{matrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right]\space\right\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\left\{ \left[\begin{matrix}3 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}2 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right] \right\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

This question is already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4253427/find-the-matrix-representation-of-a-with-respect-to-basis-given), but I don't understand it completely.

How they get this $B^{-1}AC$? I wanted to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=WQM87ZkSllk) procedure, but it doesn't
work...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a linear map $A : V \to W$ and you pick a basis  $\mathcal B_V$ and $\mathcal B_W$ then the the matrix of $A$ in those bases is *by definition* a matrix which maps the coordinates of vectors $v \in V$ in the basis $\mathcal B_V$ to coordinates of $Av \in W$ in the basis $B_W$.

Maybe the following example would help you understand

Consider the *coordinates* $(1,0,0)$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal B_V$. These are the coordinates of the *vector* $[1,1,0]$. The linear map $A$ maps the *vector* $[1,1,0]$ to the vector $[2+3,8+5] = [5,13]$ whose coordinates are (-21,34) in the basis $\mathcal B_W$.

Consider the *coordinates* $(0,1,0)$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal B_V$. These are the coordinates of the *vector* $[0,1,1]$. The linear map $A$ maps the *vector* $[0,1,1]$ to the *vector* $[7,6]$ whose coordinates are $(-5,11)$ in the basis $\mathcal B_W$.

Consider the *coordinates* $(0,0,1)$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal B_V$. These are the coordinates of the *vector* $[1,0,1]$. The linear map $A$ maps the *vector* $[1,0,1]$ to the vector $[6,9]$ whose coordinates are $(-12,21)$ in the basis $\mathcal B_W$.

Note how crucial it is to understand that the coordinates of vectors are different object than the vectors themselves.

Now notice that the matrix $C$ maps coordinates in the basis $B_V$ to the corresponding vector in $V$.

Similarly $B$ maps coordinates in $\mathcal  B_V$ to the corresponding vectors in $W$.

In the examples above we first multiplied the coordinates by $C$ then by $A$ and then by $B^{-1}$ so the matrix we are looking for is

$$ B^{-1}AC$$

---

In the video the person is working exclusively with square matrices and with a single basis. That is, he is working in the particular case $V = W$, $\mathcal B_V = \mathcal B_W$ which does not apply to your exercice.